# Rake uninitialized constant RDoc::RDoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When ever I run make I get this 'uninitialized constant RDoc::RDoc' error

> rake -T
>        (in Main)
>        rake aborted!
>        uninitialized constant RDoc::RDoc
>        C:/Ruby186/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
>        (See full trace by running task with --trace)

--edit

Running --trace it seems the only non rails code is from rdoc_rails.  Since other people seem to be able to run it fine I assume I am missing a gem or plugin but I can't figure out which.

Comment: Have you tried it with `--trace` to see anymore information?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like i have to apply both solutions for Rails (2.3.12)

1. Install rake 0.9.2
2. Install RDoc 2.4.3

> ```
> gem install rdoc --version=2.4.3
> gem update rake
> ```

I found side-effect of this solution, It caused another error like - [Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was a question of updating rake: `sudo gem update rake`

Answer (score 1):

rdoc_rails required RDoc of 2.4.3 which isn't the latest so you have to specifically install it.