# Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm having a really frustrating issue: [Rake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rake_%28software%29) is being dumb.

Here's how the problem comes about:

```
$ rails new test_app
$ rails generate scaffold new_scaffold field1:string field2:text
```

Both of those work just fine, but then when I do this,

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error.

```
(in /home/mikhail/test_app)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<module:Rake>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.0/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/home/mikhail/test_app/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I've looked about the Internet for similar/same errors, and people have had them. Just no one ever seems to solve the problem!

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

A [tweet from DHH](http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/71966528744071169) earlier. Rake .9.0 breaks Rails and several other things, you need to:

```
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

in your Gemfile.

Comment: This worked for me. I needed to do `bundle update rake` first. Then I checked with `bundle show rake`. It should say 0.8.7. Then `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: Or even better: `gem "rake", "!= 0.9.0"`. This avoids the broken 0.9.0 release, but will update to newer once a fresher release is published (removing this later won't hurt, but keeping it shouldn't hurt either).

Comment: I ran into this issue during chapter 2 of the rails tutorial (demo_app). Specifically, while running `heroku rake db:migrate`. This fixed the problem.

Comment: @Spiralis I also ran into the issue with version 0.9.2. So you may have to add that line for a few versions.

Comment: @dharmatech Yes. I just noticed myself. Pretty annoying... :(

Comment: Likewise. It is odd that Rails.rc4 is defaulting to rake 0.9.x with this issue.

Comment: this solution **worked** work for me.  Like @dharmatech, I have this issue come up in `heroku rake db:migrate` and this seemed to fix it.  remember to add and commit these changes to git before proceeding ;)

Comment: Worked for me. If you get the message, "The bundle currently has rake locked at 0.9.2.2.", just run "bundle update rake" and you'll be good to go afterwards.

Comment: This also helps when you're getting this error when you run the annotate error.

Comment: hi, I am new to rubygems, where is the gemfile located on ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: This may work for Rails, but I also had to do `sudo gem install rake` to make sure that the `rake` version I was calling from the command line was not 0.8.7.

Comment: doesn't work. ERROR:  "While executing gem ... (RuntimeError) Unknown command rake"

Comment: @KMC you have bigger issues if you can't get RAKE to run.

Answer (score 72):

I made some research just after my previous answer (sorry, I must do before it).

All problems are solved with Rake gem 0.9.2.. I followed these steps:

- I installed `gem install rake -v=0.9.2` (I had the 0.9.1 gem)
- removed the 0.9.1 with `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1`
- updated with `bundle update`
- then the `db:migrate` showed a warning, `WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please....`

  It was solved by adding the following to the Rake file.

  ```
  module ::YourApplicationName  
    class Application
      include Rake::DSL
    end
  end
  ```
- I ommited the `module ::RakeFileUtils extend Rake::FileUtilsExtend` option sugested by @databyte.

It means that the Rake gem 0.9.2 works fine!

Comment: Followed the first three steps and I got no warning so didn't bother with the rest, Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This begs me to ask... Why should I hack Rake to retain that feature?  What is Rake trying to do, and what should I use now?

Comment: @Arrumaco, What is the directory for the Rake file?

Comment: It;s worth noting that the addition to the `RakeFile` should be before `require 'rake'` - caught me out :)

Comment: I was still struggling with 0.9.2 but 0.9.3beta1 got me going. https://github.com/jimweirich/rake

Comment: same issue, but I already had rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7). Re-installing 0.9.2 seems to fix the problem though: 1) `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2` 2) `gem install rake -v=0.9.2`

Comment: @DK : Your comment is the only thing that worked. It was driving me nuts. You won't believe how many sequence of steps I followed without any results.. all i had to do was uninstall reinstall, ANY IDEA WHY THIS IS NECESSARY? is it because im using windows, and installed rails using my rubymine ide??

Comment: C:\>rake db:migrate ----------NEW LINE--------------------------

rake aborted!
undefined method `static_root=' for #<Sprockets::Environment:0x1bcaf08>

Answer (score 54):

Going through Chapter 2 of Railstutorial (demo_app) and ran into this problem. I tried all of the other answers listed here, but couldn't get it to work until I did this:

Put this in your Rakefile above require 'rake':

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

via [How to fix the uninitialized constant Rake::DSL problem on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181312/how-to-fix-the-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl-problem-on-heroku/6263256#6263256)

I also recommitted and pushed all files to Github and Heroku.

Comment: This seems like the best answer since downgrading from 0.9.2 to 0.8.7 would break some gem dependencies depending on each case, such as mine :) Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get "no such file to load -- rake/dsl_definition" when doing rake db:create

Answer (score 25):

All I needed to do was use:

```
gem install rake
```

I had version 0.9.2 already, just needed installing.

Comment: wow it worked for me. But could you explain why I have to install rake while I rake should be there already?

Comment: I'm not really an expert still, but my understanding is that there is a difference between 'installing' gems onto your PC and 'installing' them in a gem registry - I suspect this is because the Ruby installation needs to know which gems are where on your PC.  Perhaps this is something that could be automated in future, or is already automated in certain Ruby distributions...

Answer (score 19):

Reinstall the rake gem and it *should* work fine:

```
gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2 
gem install rake -v=0.9.2
```

If not, specify version '0.8.7' in your Gemfile.

Comment: this approach worked for me and I preferred not having to downgrade the version..

Comment: Worked for me as well, only for rake -v 0.9.2.2

Answer (score 10):

If not using Bundler:

```
sudo gem install rake -v 0.8.7
sudo gem uninstall rake
```

Then choose to uninstall 0.9.0.

Comment: this fixed it for me without bundler (rails 2.3.8).  Had tried to install rake 0.9.2 but that didn't fix it.  Installing 0.8.7 and uninstalling 0.9.2 was what finally worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

If like me you're stuck on rake 0.8.7, and you're using Rails 3.2.x then railties adds a requirement for Rake::DSL

To solve this, to the top of your Rakefile you should add:

```
module Rake
  module DSL
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same problem with the following steps:

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '0.9.2'
```

Then ran this on the console:

```
sudo bundle update rake
```

Then added the following lines to Rakefile:

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
include Rake::DSL
```

Answer (score 6):

Rails 3.1.rc1 has been updated.  For your own Rakefiles, you can add this before the call to load_tasks.

```
module ::YourApplicationName
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end
```

https://gist.github.com/4cd2bbe68f98f2f0249f

UPDATE: Also noticed it's already answered here as well: [Undefined method 'task' using Rake 0.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287121/undefined-method-task-using-rake-0-9-0-beta-4/5290331#5290331)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and had to use the rake 0.8.7 gem instead of 0.9.0.

Answer (score 4):

I am a Windows XP user and I had the same problem.

I entered gem "rake", "0.8.7" into the gemfile, and then typed the following from the command window.

```
bundle update rake
```

This fixed my problem.

Comment: worked for me too, as of today. just trying to code rails on Win7.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to your project path
2. Type `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle`
3. Type `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

To start server type `bundle exec rails s`. Use **bundle exec**  and you will be sure that you use right gems (required version) for your project.
Also I would recommend you to add `vendor/bundle` to `.gitignore` if you use `git` and make alias for `bundle exec`. If you use `zsh` you can follow [this approach](http://tomafro.net/2011/09/tip-automatic-bundle-exec-for-rake-and-more)

Answer (score 3):

Same as Branstar above - thanks Branstar!

- OS: Windows Vista
- Level: Completely new to Ruby on Rails
- I already had Ruby 1.9.2 installed

I followed the instructions in *[Running Rails 3 on Windows](http://accidentaltechnologist.com/ruby-on-rails/running-rails-3-on-windows/)*.

All worked up until the "rake db:migrate" part which gave me the same output as original post.

I ran:

```
gem install rake
```

I ran again:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then I was able to start the Ruby on Rails server and had everything in place.

Thanks again Branstar :-)

Answer (score 2):

I feel for you (mikhailvs), it's really frustrating. I have been going crazy for almost one full day. I even uninstalled Ruby and all its dependent files and shutdown my PC, but I still got the same problem.

What I got from the error message is the problem with Rake 0.9.2. It seems like it wasn’t fully installed. So I had to reinstall `gem install rake -v=0.9.2`

I wasn’t sure if I have rake –v0.9.1 installed. So to make sure I’m safe I tried to remove that old version with `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1`. But is showed me the error message

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d rake`
```

OK, so I checked all Rake directories on my PC, and found I only had Rake 0.9.2.
Then to check if everything went alright, I migrated with `rake db:migrate`. And it worked :)

I think I didn’t have Rake 0.9.1 because I clean-installed Ruby ([rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p180](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) - on my Windows 7 system) and all gems as well. In the meantime Rake 0.9.2 wasn’t fully installed.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling with **"gem uninstall rake"** worked for me, I had 2 versions installed, so I jest did a clean reinstall.

**"rake db:create"**, to make sure the database exists
and then **"rake db:migrate"** to seal the deal.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using Rake 0.9.2.2. I solved this problem by using bundle exec.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 2.3 editing `lib/tasks/rspec.rake` like in this commit worked for me:

https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/pull/11/files

Answer (score 0):

Install rake 0.8.7 and uninstall 0.9.2.2

```
$ gem install rake -v 0.8.7
$ gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2.2
```

Now use

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

i think this will help you
;)

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

it works for me.