# Rake db:create failing in fresh rails 3.1 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

On the 3.1RC, I have created a new app, and when I try to run the db:create job I'm getting this:

```
[15:38][*********@***********:~/**********/db(master)]$ rake db:create
(in /Users/*********/*********)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
```

any ideas appreciated.

Comment: This is a known issue with Rake 0.9.0. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl

Comment: thanks. don't know why that previous thread didn't show up in my search. either way...that did the trick..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

In your gemfile, as stated rake 0.9.0 breaks a few things.