# Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, railstutorial.org

I am working through the Ruby on Rails 3 tutorial book and typed the following on the command line:

```
rake db:migrate
```

which produced the following warning.

```
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please Include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.

WARNING: DSL method DemoApp::Application#task called at /Users/imac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
```

I am not sure what to do about it or how to work with it. I don't know any other command for Rake.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I found this in Stack Overflow question *[Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl)*. It refers to a @DHH tweet.

Put the following in your Gemfile

```
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

You may see something like

```
rake aborted!
You have already activated Rake 0.9.1 ...
```

I still had a copy of Rake 0.9.1 in my directory so I deleted it.

You can "delete" Rake 0.9.1 by running the following command:

```
gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1
```

If you have multiple versions of the gem installed, you'll be prompted to pick a version.

After 0.9.1 was cleaned out, I ran

```
bundle update rake
```

and was finally able to create my database files. I was using `rake db:create`, but it should work for `rake db:migrate` as well.

I hope it helps.

Comment: That did not work for me. I had to actually remove rake 0.9.1 > gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1 and then > bundle update Thanks
Antonio

Comment: I agree with Antonio - when I said to remove rake 0.9.1 I meant through using `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1`. My mistake for not making it clear. Thanks for the clarification Antonio! Cheers, Brian

Comment: I don’t think it’s good to deliberately use old libraries, when newer one can be made to work, seeing comment below.

Comment: The more simple solution is the one suggested by NPatel below. Just add one line to Rakefile.

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this resolution. It still came up with the same error after uninstalling rake 0.9.1 or 0.9.2 then running bundle update.

Answer (score 111):

Adding `include Rake::DSL` to the Rakefile before the applications load_tasks were called also worked for me.

So in the above user's case before the `DemoApp::Application.load_tasks` in the Rakefile.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed my "WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated." problem.

Comment: Is this the proper way to fix this issue?

Comment: @Marc, currently this is the only fix I know off without upgrading to rails 3.0.8 or higher. This issue is resolved in that release: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/83f257fc4862642af29056cb5b7dfef6e1303754. If you find a better fix please let me know. Also, according to the warning I would think that it is the proper fix.

Comment: This is the solution I went with. I'd prefer to simply add the line than to play games with which version of Rake works with what.

Comment: This worked for me with 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.7 with Rake 0.9.2

Comment: This works for me as well with Rails 3.0 ,ruby 1.9.2 Rake 0.9.2.

Comment: This worked for me for server load and console load, but I still get the warnings when running rake db:migrate etc.. any ideas?

Comment: NB: This caused a subtle issue for me, where the following modules were being mixed into ActiveRecord::Base: Rake::DSL, Rake::FileUtilsExt, FileUtils, FileUtils::StreamUtils_. One of them (I think FileUtils) was overwriting a field called #link on some of the models with a private method used for creating symlinks.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem on Windows with the installer.  Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.9.
Here is what I did:

```
bundle update rake
bundle show rake
```

After doing that I was running rake 0.9.2.

Then I updated the Rakefile in application root folder as follows:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
# If you named your application something other than SampleApp, change that below
module ::SampleApp
    class Application
        include Rake::DSL
    end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
    extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end

SampleApp::Application.load_tasks
```

As noted in the comment, make sure the name of your app is correct in the two appropriate lines above.

Comment: And to get the `heroku rake db:migrate` command to work, I also had to add `require 'rake/dsl_definition'` to the rakefile (above the require 'rake' line).

Comment: Doing all of this works for me, but isn't needed. The suggestion by NPatel handled it fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this on later versions of Rails (like 3.+) you may also want to verify that your environment is clean by using RVM http://beginrescueend.com/ and creating a specific ruby & gemset for your projects.

Use an .rvmrc file on a per-project basis, this will guarantee you aren't getting older system gems into your projects.  Which has bitten me before.

This prevents having to monkey around with generated Rakefiles & such.

Answer (score 0):

bundle exec rake db:migrate will solve your ruby version issues

Comment: This only works if you have a working version of rake in your Gemfile, and typing "rake" is using some different version installed in your PATH