# Unable to call rake db:drop, have to use bundle exec rake db:drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this Routing Error and rake routes error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217674/what-is-this-routing-error-and-rake-routes-error)

I'm getting these error messages when calling 'rake db:drop' or any rake commands and I've to use 'bundle exec rake db:drop" instead. Why is that so?

```
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:4: warning: already initialized constant MAJOR
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant MINOR
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:6: warning: already initialized constant BUILD
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant NUMBERS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/version.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:26: warning: already initialized constant RAKEVERSION
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/early_time.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant EARLY
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: warning: already initialized constant WINDOWS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:28: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_RAKEFILES
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task_arguments.rb:73: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY_TASK_ARGS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/invocation_chain.rb:49: warning: already initialized constant EMPTY
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:143: warning: already initialized constant Commands
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:44: warning: already initialized constant ARRAY_METHODS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:47: warning: already initialized constant MUST_DEFINE
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:51: warning: already initialized constant MUST_NOT_DEFINE
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:55: warning: already initialized constant SPECIAL_RETURN
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:61: warning: already initialized constant DELEGATING_METHODS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:364: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PATTERNS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_list.rb:370: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_IGNORE_PROCS
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:64: warning: already initialized constant FileList
/Volumes/Data/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake.rb:65: warning: already initialized constant RakeFileUtils
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425191/rake-error-warning-already-initialized-constant-major (in which I point to an earlier one--I'm gonna see how many layers we can go ;)

Comment: Thanks for helping me to close it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `bundle exec` to ensure your commands are run through the proper dependencies.  I don't have a specific answer as to why your error is occurring, but you do want to use `bundle exec`.  Yehuda Katz has a much more in depth write up at http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/