# Executing rake task throws error - use rbconfig instead of obsolete and deprecated config

Tags: rake, selenium-rc

we are trying to run our selenium scripts using Selenium RC in Windows machine. we've created a rake file with a task that will run all our spec files(run_all_spec)

installed:

ruby 1.9.3,

rake version 0.9.1,

rspec 1.2.8

selenium-client 1.2.18

but we're getting "Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated" Error

following [Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199301/global-access-to-rake-dsl-methods-is-deprecated), we did downgrade our rake version to 0.8.7

but when we call the command "rake run_all_spec", we get the error:

Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.

we also tried manually running our scripts using the "spec" command trying to isolate the problem if its rspec but we're able to run the script so we it must be a rake issue.

Please help.

Thanks in advance,
girlie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to run my rspec files using rake now. what we did was downgrade to 
ruby 1.8.7, 
rake (0.8.7) and 
rspec (1.2.9)