# How do you rake a Heroku database?

Tags: database, heroku, rake, dsl, dbmigrate

I have an application on [Heroku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku). However, whenever I change my database locally and then push the changes to the application, the database doesn't not change.

I realized that I need to run a rake on the Heroku database. However when I try `heroku rake db:migrate` I get the following error.

> rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rake::DSL`

How do I solve this problem?

I've been improvising with `heroku db:push`, but that will not be able to hold because it deletes the current database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the new [Cedar Stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar), you should use

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: How do you move from default stack to cedar?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, as far as I know you should create a new application with something like:
heroku create --stack cedar
and then push your git repo to it.
I also had some problems with my Gemfile. This one https://gist.github.com/040c2e18ef8708a30bf4 worked so far for me on the Cedar stack.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
heroku rake db:version
```

Source:

> http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Answer (score 0):

Append w/ "heroku" or just type "heroku" in your terminal for instructions

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

Comment: this should be heroku rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Your error for rake aborted! Uninitialized constant `Rake::DSL` is probably down to rake versions - see Stack Overflow question *[Ruby on Rails and Rake problems: uninitialized constant Rake::DSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl)* for a fix.