# Cannot Deploy App w/ Heroku - Rake::DSL Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku, rake

I'm using Rails v. 3.0.9 and have pushed the app to Heroku.  When I view the custom Heroku domain I get the following message from Heroku:

"We're sorry, but something went wrong.
We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

I run `heroku logs` and don't seem to get any error messages.  The only error I encounter with Heroku seems to be when I run `heroku rake db:migrate` with which I get the following in return:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
```

*Note*: I'm new to Rails and to Heroku.  I'm not quite understanding the difference between production and development environments.  Do I need to be in production for Heroku to work?  At the moment, I'm using localhost3000 to view my app.  Thanks guys!

Comment: This might be a duplicate to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/rails-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog post about it here:

http://codeglot.com/posts/13-you_have_already_activated_rake_0_9_2

There are two solutions. Use an older version of rake or require DSL.