# Rake error Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try doing rake db:migrate I get this error

```
rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
/home/laptop/RubymineProjects/website2/Rakefile:10
```

What do I have to do to fix this? I tried with multiple different rake versions. I'm running Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.8.7 and Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl

Comment: Which version of Rake are you using? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl

Answer (score 6):

Include this in your Rakefile

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

Then bundle install and you're (hopefully) good to go :)

---

If this didn't work, try the following:

You're probably using Rake 0.87 so `gem install rake -v=0.9.2` is something you should do.

Then remove old rake with `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.1`

Then `bundle update`

And if you still have any problem then...

Add the following  to your Rake file

```
module ::YourApplicationName  
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end
```

Comment below if you are having any problem after all this little hacks...

Answer (score 0):

on Debian Squeeze this is what I do to fix that:

[Configure squeeze-backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/Instructions/) and upgrade rubygems

```
apt-get install -t squeeze-backports rubygems
```

remove rake and it's executable

```
gem uninstall rake
rm /usr/bin/rake
```

install rake again, now the executable file will be /usr/local/bin/rake and error is gone

```
gem install rake
```