# rake db:miagrate aborted abnormal: rake aborted! uninitialized constant Rake::DSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, dbmigrate

Anyone could help me?
I searched the same problem, but I can't figure out a solution still.
I ran successfully with "bundle update" "bundle install" but when running "rake db:migrate" I got the following problem...

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<clas
s:TaskLib>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:6:in `<modu
le:Rake>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:3:in `<top
(required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.11/lib/rdoc/task.rb:37:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/tasks/documentation
.rake:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `blo
ck in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each
'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top
 (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:215:
in `initialize_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:139:
in `load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:i
n `method_missing'
C:/F/desktop/Projects/recle/recle/rails/eway/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

Comment: seems duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran `gem install rake` and problem got solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Rakefile above require 'rake':

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
```

OR if the above solution does not work,

write this in your gemfile for rake

```
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
```

and go to command prompt and write.

```
gem uninstall rake
```

This will uninstall the existing rake gem.

Then type bundle update in your project folder which will install rake 9.8.7 again.

And enjoy rails :).

Comment: Dont forget "bundle exec rake db:migrate"

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran `gem install rake` and problem got solved!

Comment: Could someone explain why gem install rake solve the problem? I though rake is part of the standard installation