# bundle exec rspec VS rspec spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

Ruby 1.9.2 Rails 3.1

Here is the problem `bundle exec rspec spec/` does not work, but `rspec spec/` runs ok.

When I run `c:\RailsInstaller\work\apptwit>bundle exec rspec spec/` (this is the directory where my app is located, so the path to spec would not need to be specified)
I receive

```
c:/RailsInstaller/work/apptwit/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- spec_he lper (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/work/apptwit/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:i
n `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:i
n `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:i
n `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:i
n `load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in
`run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_i
n_process'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block
 in autorun'
```

/spec directory exists as exists spec_helper.rb in it.

So basically I have 2 questions:

1. Why doesn't `bundle exec rspec spec/` work while `rspec spec/` has no problems?
2. What is the difference between those two commands?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285161/what-does-it-do-by-bundle-exec-rake-dbmigrate/8285201#8285201). `bundle exec` changes your `$PATH`, or `%PATH%` in case of Windows. As a result, by using `bundle exec rspec` you're calling the RSpec's version which is specified in your `Gemfile`. `rspec` ran without Bundler executes the one in your `$PATH`.

The error you see might be caused by the fact that the RSpec version in your `$PATH` is incompatible with Rails version you're working with. The version installed and executed by Bundler (with `bundle exec rspec`) is compatible and works fine.