# Rspec undefined local variable or method `matcher_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I get an issue when launching rspec

```
Failure/Error:
       expect {
         post :create, params: {tag: attributes_for(:tag)}
       }.to change(Tag, :count).by(1)

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `matcher_name' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Change:0x000000094f7348>
       Did you mean?  match_unless_raises
```

**Edit :**

it only occurs when I do

```
rspec
```

instead of

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `bundle exec` with your project-related binaries. Without it, a wrong version is likely picked up. Check it.

```
rspec --version
bundle exec rspec --version
```

Answer (score 1):

The console error log says probably you are supplying wrong method name, That's clear. Can you try changing the name of the method or variable which you are using?

You can also refer this for getting the difference between those two commands
 [bundle exec rspec VS rspec spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288143/bundle-exec-rspec-vs-rspec-spec)

Comment: "That's clear" - except that method name is nowhere in sight. How is that clear?