# Problems running rspec 2.8.0.rc1 within rbenv defined ruby 1.9.2p290 environment

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rbenv

This works:

```
[rails31]$ ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb 
*.

Pending:
  Domain add some examples to (or delete) /home/keith/Code/elements2/spec/models/domain_spec.rb
    # Not Yet Implemented
    # ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb:4

Finished in 0.04241 seconds
2 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

However I'm trying to run from [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), which executes the following command:

```
[rails31]$ /home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb 
/home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby: no Ruby script found in input (LoadError)
```

Breaking that down enough to execute I get this:

```
[rails31]$ /home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb 
/home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:335:in `rescue in debug=':  (RuntimeError)
**************************************************
no such file to load -- ruby-debug

If you have it installed as a ruby gem, then you need to either require
'rubygems' or configure the RUBYOPT environment variable with the value
'rubygems'.

...
```

This is actually where I started in the first place - I know rspec respects the "[dont require rubygems](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-dev)" rule, so maybe I need to run rake. The big problem I have with this error is that "ruby-debug" does NOT exist for ruby1.9 - it should be ruby-debug19 - so whats happening here?

So anyway, I tried with Rake:

```
[rails31]$ rake spec ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb 
(in /home/keith/Code/elements2)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
...
```

I've tried Googling the problem but nothing obvious is coming up, so really I'm stumped

UPDATE:

Well after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl) I've managed to resolve the rake issue, however now when I run rake I get this:

```
[rails31]$ rake spec
(in /home/keith/Code/elements2)
/home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/models/domain_spec.rb
/home/keith/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.8.0.rc1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:335:in `rescue in debug=':  (RuntimeError)
...
```