# Persistent Rake DSL method warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rake

Alright, well I'm trying to fix this problem again. I followed [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085960/348191) to eliminate the error by reverting to version 0.8.7, which worked the first time. However, now I'm trying to use cucumber and I'm getting it all again.

I tried it again by running `gem uninstall rake -v=0.9.2.2` which lists all the gem dependencies. Successfully uninstalled. Then I ran `bundle update rake`. Using rake (0.8.7). Cool. `rake -V`. rake, version 0.9.2.2. wat. Same problems return. What am I missing? I thought 9.2 was supposed to fix this bug anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think this fix is obsolete. Rake 0.9.0 got fixed, and 0.9.2.2 is certainly working. You want to uninstall and completely eradicate rake 0.8.x. Try something like:

```
gem list -d rake
```

The `-d` switch will show the installation directories.  If you're using RVM, there may be multiple search paths that get hit, running `rvm info` will tell you the search path and preference ordering.  Depending on the system you're on, your OS may also ship with an old rake version. Try uninstalling everything other than the local gemset (if using RVM) or the latest rake (if not using RVM).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the rake gem uninstall sounds like you have Rake in your default gemset, check `~/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems` It will no doubt have rake in it