# Rails 2.2.3 and newest Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I've got problem with rake tasks. When I tried to execute any rake task I was getting following error: `uninitialized constant Rake::DSL`. Of course I searched through stackoverflow before this question and I founded some useful posts, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6686628/698919

Unfortunately after above fix I am still getting another errors, which are not mentioned in any posts:

```
    rake gems:install
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already       initialized constant RUBY
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already                 initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `deprecate' for #<Rake::Application:0x7f4c3b3eeb38>
    /home/arti/domeny/domain/ror/Rakefile:8
```

My Rakefile:

```
    require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))
    require 'rake/dsl_definition'
    require 'rake'
    require 'rake/testtask'
    require 'rake/rdoctask'
    require 'tasks/rails'
```

I've  also tried to downgrade Rake to 0.8.7 version. Afterwards, rake tasks were working properly, but other gems didnt work and I had to get back to newest version of rake (0.9.2.2). I know that I should asap migrate to newest version of Rails, but now I need temporary fix. I can handle without migrations, but I need rake to indexing models through thinking_sphinx.

Comment: You really, really want to use rvm.  It would simplify your life greatly in situations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this. Here is proper Rakefile:

```
    require(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'config', 'boot'))
    require 'rake/dsl_definition'
    require 'rake'
    include Rake::DSL
    require 'rake/testtask'
    require 'rdoc/task'

    require 'tasks/rails'

    begin
      require 'thinking_sphinx/tasks'
    rescue LoadError
      puts "You can't load Thinking Sphinx tasks unless the thinking-sphinx gem is $
    end
```