# Rails:: rake db:create does not return anything on Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have following configuration:

```
Ruby version              1.9.2 (i386-mingw32)
RubyGems version          1.7.2
Rack version              1.2
Rails version             3.0.3
Active Record version     3.0.1
Action Pack version       3.0.3
Active Resource version   3.0.3
Action Mailer version     3.0.3
Active Support version    3.0.3
```

I am running `rake db:create` command but it returns nothing and using trace, I find following output on the screen

```
E:\Crawler\server>rake db:create --trace
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
rake aborted!

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `query'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:312:in `execute
```

When I run rake db:migrate command, it returns following:

```
E:\Crawler\server> rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Unknown database 'marketplace_development'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My rake file is:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'

module ::Marketplace
  class Application
    include Rake::DSL
  end
end

module ::RakeFileUtils
  extend Rake::FileUtilsExt
end

Marketplace::Application.load_tasks
```

database.yml file:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
#
# Install the MySQL driver:
#   gem install mysql2
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Marketplace_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Can anybody tell me what's happening here? I have not created any database explicitly on my own. Do I need to create a database with some tool? I have seen other SO threads but no avail.

**Edit1::**

As suggested by Rogier, I opened up `MySQL command line client` and ran following command

```
create schema marketplace_development;
```

Now both commands `db:create` and `db:migrate` hang up upon execution.

**Edit2::**

Every time I restart my command window and start a server with `rails server`, it asks me to install now ActiveRecord mysql2. I install with `gem install activerecord-msql2-adpater`, uninstall `mysql2 (0.3.11-x86-ming32)` , update my `Gemfile.lock` file to just have     `mysql2 (0.2.7)` .

I run `bundle install` and start my rails server which is started successfully. But I am not able to view the server in browser. `http://localhost:3000` and `http://127.0.0.1:3000` never return the page. I have tried with `port 30001` also, but in vain.

**Edit3**

I stopped my server, created a new rails project `rails new myApp` , moved into folder `myApp` and started the server. It asked me to do `bundle install` because it couldn't find `sqlite3 ruby`. I did so, and started the server and I was able to browse it through above URL.

I moved to my previous server folder and it still doesn't work. What could be wrong in this application?

Comment: Have you given proper database credentials in database.yml file?

Comment: I mean to say, rails will configure database credentials as `username: '', and password: 'root'`. So change there if you have your own credentials.

Comment: When installing mysql, I didn't provide any password for root, so I assume, there is no password for root. And I didn't create any database either. Should I create it with some tool? Toad 6.3? Thanks.

Comment: Ok..do one thing. Open your mysql GUI. And do let me know with what credentials you have gone inside.

Comment: If your username is root, and password is not for the root. Change the database.yml file as I will send to in the answer box.

Comment: Sorry for late response. When I open MySQL 5.5 command line client, it asks for password. I just press enter and then it shows me command prompt for inputs like mysql> .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making **Edit3**, I realized that there might be something wrong with my own project in terms of required dependencies. During the course of installation, I faced many issues and to solve them, I tried every tip given on SO and other forums without knowing even if it's compatible with my existing installation or not. Initially I installed `Ruby 1.8.7` and `rails 3.1.x` without looking at `Gemfile`, which as a newbie I didn't know its purpose. Then I installed `Ruby 1.9.2` and started doing random installations.

And on them was installation of `rake 10.0.2` while my project required `rake 0.8.7`. Since I didn't know much about which rails server is compatible with which version of Ruby, I was trying installation whatever was given on internet, desperately wanting it to be working. **Bad thing to do!!**

**Solution:**

I uninstalled `rake 10.0.2` and went back to `rake 0.8.7`. This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085610/ruby-on-rails-and-rake-problems-uninitialized-constant-rakedsl) helped me to get it working. Uninstalled `mysql (0.3.11)` and installed `mysql2 (0.2.7)`

**Lesson learnt:** Don't do random installations without looking at project requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your db name lowercase (mysql **can** be case sensitive).

You can create a db simple by using mysql command:

```
mysql -u root -p
create schema marketplace_development;
quit
```

the above command is anyway useful to check if the credentials are working properly.

see if the migration then works.

db:create should create the db for you

for all db tasks:

```
rake -T db
```

try this basic example:

```
// im running
MySQL 5.5.25-log
Rails 3.2.2

// from the command line try this
rails new my_sql_test -d mysql

// if the gems are not installed, then run:
bundle install

// update your user/pass
rake db:create
// you get no response

mysql -u root
show schemas; 

// schema is created?
```

Comment: I changed Marketplace to lower letter marketplace but it didn't work. And on the MySQL command Client, I ran mysql> create schema marketplace_development;
And result was = Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec). After this, migrate command also hangs up like create command.

Comment: did you try to reinstall your mysql2 adapter?

Comment: I tried it also. Please see Edit2 if that was you were suggesting?

Comment: your edit2 is about sqlite? i added a simple example, give it a try (to narrow it down). For me after using 'rails new' it installs the gems. you might (depending on the Rails version) run 'bundle install'

Comment: thanks for your response. I got everything working as I posted Answer below. It's just I am not able to mark it as a Answer within next 16 hours.

Comment: Great! it was the socket? depending on os and config its not always written in /tmp/mysql.sock (you need to check your my.cnf for that).

Comment: No. It was not about socket. I left my database.yml as default (given above). It was just installation of wrong versions for both Ruby, Rails and mysql2.

Comment: sure,no problem. please mark this question solved. so it doesn't show up under 'unsolved questions', thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your username is root, and password is not for the root. Change the database.yml file as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: Marketplace_development
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
```

I think, the above will work for you. Go ahead.

Comment: Write `host: 127.0.0.1` instead `host: localhost` once.

Comment: Tried both migrate and create commands, no luck. I also commented and uncommented this line  'socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ' but both commands just hang up upon execution.