# rake aborted ! name error uninitialized constant Rails :: API :: Rdoc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i am trying to run `rake db:migrate` in my rails I get this error:

```
rake aborted ! name error uninitialized constant Rails :: API :: Rdoc
```

I am a newbie in the ruby on rails I was following the youtube tutorial to build a web blog application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY
but in the video it runs rake db just fine, i am so confused why I got rake aborted error in the command prompt, the migration file code is:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :body

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

end
```

would you please help me with this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this error has nothing to do with your migration. Somewhere in your app, I think you are referencing `Rdoc`. RDoc is used to produce Ruby documentation, it's pretty much always written as `RDoc` (capital 'd'). Try and find that.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me more details about this please? i am kinda new on RoR and i am eager to solve his issue.

Comment: i can not run any rake command so far, is that something  requires me edit in gemfile or rakefile? , I have tried the solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993435/rake-uninitialized-constant-rdocrdoc  this but its not working for me